# Socket.io Server can't send data to the client

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, websocket, socket.io

I'm trying to send data to the client via Socket.io. 
If the connection is established, I'll receive a message. But outside of the socket.on('connection') the client doesn't get anything.

### UPDATE!

## CLIENT.JS

```
import io from 'socket.io-client' 

const socket = io('http://192.168.178.54:3000', {
  transports: ['websocket', 'polling'],
})
socket.on('connection', data => socket.emit('recruiter_id', recruiter_id)) // TOP
socket.on('update_contact', data => console.log) // FLOP
socket.on('connection', data => console.log) // FLOP
socket.on('haha', data => console.log) // FLOP
```

## SERVER.JS

```
this.io = require('socket.io')(this.server, {transports : ['polling', 'websocket']});
this.io.on('connect', (socket) => {
    console.log('connected');
    socket.emit('update_contact', {bla: "hi"});
    socket.emit('connection', {'michael' : 'ist doof'});
    socket.emit('haha', "hi");    // This will be emitted
    socket.on('recruiter_id', (id) => {
        this.socketMap.set(id, id);
        socket.emit('update_contact', {bla: "hi"});        
    })
    socket.emit('update_contact', {bla: "hi"});
});
```

The server is running on a different machine.

Comment: `outside of the socket.on('connection') the client doesn't get anything` What else is your client listening to?

Comment: I also listen to 'connected', but don't get any data back

Comment: My answer was useful? Say thanks by upvoting. It fixed your issue? Please accept it :-)

Comment: Sorry, but It didn't work at all!

Comment: In Dev Tools Network panel I got a 101: Switching Protocols. Does it have something to do with that?

Answer (score 0):

Your client does not listen to `connection` because the arrow function is never executed. You should listen to `connect`, not `connected`. Try this:

CLIENT.JS

```
socket.on('connect', () => console.log('client connected'));
socket.on('connection', (data) => console.log('connection:', data));
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing transports from client and server was the solution.